# ¿Como leer un archivo que tiene una matriz de FxC y guardarlo en un arreglo int de las mismas dimensiones? (JAVA)

Tags: java, archivo, bucles, matrices, split

La particularidad de este problema es que la matriz de FxC que esta en el archivo es variable, por lo que busco que la lectura del archivo y la forma de guardarlo en el arreglo se acople a los distintos tamaños de matrices que podrían haber.
Aquí adjunto un ejemplo de como se encontraría la matriz en el .txt

[image: Así se ve la matriz]

Por ahora solo llevo esta parte de código la cual me lee el archivo y me lo almacena en un vector String, mas sin embargo busco la manera de alojarlo en una matriz int o Integer, y recalco que me gustaría que el código se adaptara a leer cualquier tamaño de matriz, espero y alguien pueda ayudarme, de antemano gracias.

```
public void leerArchivo1() {

    System.out.println("Ingrese la ruta del archivo");
    ruta = sc.next();
    String[] arreglo = new String[0];


    try {

        FileReader r = new FileReader(ruta);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(r);

        String temp = "";

        while (temp != null) {

            temp = buffer.readLine();

            String x;
            x = temp;

            arreglo = x.split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(" " + arreglo[i]);
            }

            if (temp == null)
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Dicho código me compila de esta manera, la cual no es de mucha ayuda a lo que me gustaría obtener.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuando vas a leer el archivo, ya sabes de cuantas filas y columnas es la matriz??

Comment: FxC, me gustaria que se adaptara a cualquier tamaño

Comment: el problema con las matrices o arreglos es que no son variables y no se pueden redimencionar, de esta forma al no conocer los tamaños iniciales debe primero procesar todos los datos, calcular las dimensiones de la matriz, crear la matriz y volcar los datos a la misma.

Comment: ¿Tienes que guardar el contenido del fichero obligatoriamente en arrays? No puedes guardarlo en otra estructura más dinámica como una lista de listas de enteros por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver tu problema como lo planteas, te recomiendo hacer uso de un arraylist

```
try {

        FileReader r = new FileReader(ruta);
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(r);

        String temp = "";
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((temp = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(temp);//Lee las n lineas de tu archivo
        }
        String[] numbers = lines.get(0).split(",");
        int x = numbers.length;//Obtenemos la cantidad de numeros por linea
        int y = lines.size();//Obtenemos la cantidad de lineas
        int[][] matrix = new int[x][y];
        //Llenamos la matriz linea por linea
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            String[] line = lines.get(j).split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");//Imprime un salto de linea cada que se llena una fila de la matriz
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
```